# NavigationLink is not clickable after returning to the view from it's child view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

My app has a multilevel layout
AView -> BView -> CView -> DView.

I change

> window.rootViewController

to BView in order to "pop" 2 top views but for some reason when i come back to BView it's NavigationLink is not clickable.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? It seems like BView doesn't know that it became visible..

AView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AView: View {
    
    init() {
        print("AView init")
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: BView()) {
                    Text("This is View A, now go to View B.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BView: View {
    init() {
        print("BView init")
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CView()) {
                Text("This is View B, now go to View C.")
        }
    }
}

struct CView: View {
    
    init() {
        print("CView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DView()) {
                Text("This is View C, now go to View D.")
        }
    }
}

struct DView: View {
    init() {
        print("DView init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            print("button pressed")
            (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.toBView()

        },
               label: {
            Text("Back!")
        })

    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let aView =     AView()
        
        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: aView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    
    func toBView() {
        let bView = BView()
        window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: bView)
    }

}
```

Comment: There is nothing bad in provided SwiftUI view... it's better to show what/how do you do with rootViewController - there is the reason of broken SwiftUI behavior.

Comment: sorry, i've just updated the code for SceneDelegate

Comment: Well... it is not "pop", you just destroy everything (ie. entire view hierarchy) and create the only `BView` at root level.

Comment: but why does it appear with non-clickable NavigationLink ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asperi already stated the problem.. you are setting BView as root level. Actually changing that, shouldn't be a big problem.

But back to your question why does the `NavigationLink` won't work anymore. Thats because ViewA, which contains the `NavigationView` is not in the RootLevel anymore. Hence you will need to provide a new NavigationView, but only and only when BView is the root view.

So inside BView, add a parameter `isRootView`, which you will set only to true when you call it from your `SceneDelegate`

```
struct BView: View {
    init(isRootView: Bool = false) {
        print("BView init")
        self.isRootView = isRootView
    }
    
    var isRootView : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        if isRootView {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: CView()) {
                        Text("This is View B, now go to View C.")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationLink(destination: CView()) {
                    Text("This is View B, now go to View C.")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And here the call from SceneDelegate

```
func toBView() {
    let bView = BView(isRootView: true)
    window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: bView)
}
```